# Listing human-readable enums

Tags: java, performance, reflection

I'm trying to do some util class to operate on enums - convert Enums to its special strings representation via interface method.
String stored in enum constructors.

```
public enum StatusEnum implements HumanReadableEnum {
    NOT_VERIFIED("Not verified message"),
    INVALID("Invalid message"),
    APPROVED("Approved message");

    private String text;
    public String getHumanReadable(){   // single method of HumanReadableEnum
        return text;
    }
```

For example instead of `HumanReadableEnum[] v = StatusEnum.values()` 
 I want to get List of inner text messages and do it in generic style.

So now I made a `toHumanReadableCollection` method:

```
public class EnumUtils {
    public static <CustomEnum extends Enum & HumanReadableEnum, E extends Class<CustomEnum>> 
    List<String> toHumanReadableCollection(E enumClass){
        Enum[] values = enumClass.getEnumConstants();
        List<String> humanReadableCollection = new ArrayList<>(values.length);

        for (Enum value : values) {
            String stringRepresentation = ((CustomEnum)value).getHumanReadable();
            humanReadableCollection.add(stringRepresentation);
        }
        return humanReadableCollection;
    }
}
```

As a result I can do something like:

```
List<String> messagesOfEnum1 = EnumUtils.toHumanReadableCollection(MyEnum1.class);
List<String> messagesOfEnum2 = EnumUtils.toHumanReadableCollection(MyEnum2.class);
```

And have code of `toHumanReadableCollection` in single place. But I have some doubts about performance.
So could somebody help me to understand the cost of my code? :) Did I touched the reflection?)

Comment: Have you by any chance come across the `toString()` method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Method header

Your method header can be improved, the generic type `E` is not necessary, it can instead be written as:

```
public static <CustomEnum extends Enum & HumanReadableEnum> 
    List<String> toHumanReadableCollection(Class<CustomEnum> enumClass){
```

Type parameters should generally be one-character names, so this would be better as:

```
public static <E extends Enum & HumanReadableEnum> 
    List<String> toHumanReadableCollection(Class<E> enumClass) {
```

#### Compiler warning

You're getting a compiler warning here:

```
String stringRepresentation = ((CustomEnum)value).getHumanReadable();
```

All you care about is the `getHumanReadable` method, which is in the `HumanReadableEnum` interface, so make that:

```
String stringRepresentation = ((HumanReadableEnum)value).getHumanReadable();
```

#### Naming and interface

`HumanReadableEnum` should instead be `HumanReadable`, there's no need to keep `Enum` in the name, there's no need to restrict the interface to only enums either.

#### Your questions

Reflection? Yes, this line of code is using reflection:

```
Enum[] values = enumClass.getEnumConstants();
```

Time complexity? \$O(n)\$, it is linear to the number of enum constants.

#### Java 8

In Java 8, you could replace your method with this:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(StatusEnum.values())
   .map(HumanReadableEnum::getHumanReadable)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or, as a general method, and also incorporating the earlier suggestions:

```
public static <E extends Enum & HumanReadable>
  List<String> toHumanReadableCollection(Class<E> enumClass) {
    Enum[] values = enumClass.getEnumConstants();
    return Arrays.stream(values)
       .map(e -> ((HumanReadable)e).getHumanReadable())
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

There's often a benefit of using Streams, I suggest you try to learn the Java 8 Stream API at some point.

Comment: an alternative would be: `map(HumanReadable::cast).map(HumanReasable::getHumanReadable)` - not sure if it s better or not though...

Answer (score 5):

> Have you by any chance come across the `toString()` method? - [*myself*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106339/java-reflection-enums-and-performance#comment194871_106339)

Just to elaborate a bit more on my comment... Is your solution perhaps looking for a non-existent problem in the first place? From [`Enum.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString--)'s Javadoc:

> Returns the name of this enum constant, as contained in the declaration. This method may be overridden, though it typically isn't necessary or desirable. **An enum type should override this method when a more "programmer-friendly" string form exists.**

And the best thing of all, `toString()` comes free with every [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--):

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the `toString` method returns a **string that "textually represents" this object**. The result should be a concise but informative representation **that is easy for a person to read**. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

Somewhat coincidentally, I have [an answer on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/284385/119814) to a similar question that may be of interest too.

The `toString()` method can be used as such:

```
enum StatusEnum {
    NOT_VERIFIED("Not verified message"),
    INVALID("Invalid message"),
    APPROVED("Approved message");

    private final String toString;

    private StatusEnum(String toString) {
        this.toString = toString;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return toString;
    }
}
```

And the Java 8 approach for this may be:

```
private static <E extends Enum<E>> List<String> toStringForAll(Class<E> clazz) {
    return EnumSet.allOf(clazz).stream().map(Enum::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: I think that when using an `EnumSet`, the order of the enums is not guaranteed. I like the suggestion of `toString` though, couldn't you even make that `.map(Object::toString)` ?

Comment: @SimonForsberg [`EnumSet`'s Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) says that  "the iterator returned by the `iterator` method traverses the elements in their *natural order*", so the ordering is guaranteed. `Object::toString` works too, but `Enum::toString` saves 2 characters. :D

Comment: Oh, I have learned something new about `EnumSet` then!

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the source for EnumMap (which needs to derive enum values from enum class object as well), you can see that it uses: `SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess().getEnumConstantsShared(keyType);`

Where SharedSecrets is documented as:

> A repository of "shared secrets", which are a mechanism for calling implementation-private methods in another package without using reflection.

So if you *really* cared about performance, you might consider using this method. Be aware, though, that you will be served the *original* enum array this way and could do some pretty nasty stuff by mutating it. (Cf. [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078599/usage-of-sun-misc-sharedsecrets).)